# Getting Error while deleting mysql.general_log table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

5, getting error while executing below query,

```
delete from mysql.general_log
```

Error getting after executing above query,

```
Error Code: 1556
You can't use locks with log tables.
```

can somebody please help me to resolve above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first rename the table and then try to delete it and then revert back ie., change the table name back to the original one.

The second [alternative solution](http://www.serveridol.com/2012/09/19/mysqldump-got-error-1556-you-cant-use-locks-with-log-tables/) is this:

> You may need to disable “–lock-tables” option on your dump statement
>   ie –lock-tables=0 . What my assumption is when we use “–lock-tables”
>   option, the current table which is being backed up will be operating
>   on “read only” mode to avoid further write operations during the time.
>   The cached query which containing “write’ operation will be executed
>   later once after the table dump has been done. Pls note that skipping
>   this option is not recommended in production mode.
>
> I made this changes because of since the Amazon RDS does allow only remote access
>   even though I set daily backup and retention period in RDS web
>   interface properly. This custom backup is taken for my surety even
>   though AWS RDS handle it better.
>
> ```
> $mysqldump –all-database –lock-tables=0 -uusername -h hostname -p’password’ -B | bzip2 > /backup/db/domain-00-00.2012.bz2
> ```

Answer (score 9):

To clear all Data from the Table you can use

TRUNCATE mysql.general_log

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u dbUsername -p dbPassword --lock-tables=0> data.sql
```

works fine for me.